# Error running UI Automation from command line

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I think this is a first - I'm getting an error and the exception constant that I'm getting back returns nothing when I search for it on Google.

Basically I'm trying to run UI Automation on my iOS app from the CLI and am getting the following error message:

> 2013-02-22 13:12:17.820 ScriptAgent[16626:2e07] +[UIAXElement initialize]: UIAutomation never received kAXAccessibilityLoaded.  Waited 20.02 seconds.
>
> 2013-02-22 13:12:17.826 ScriptAgent[16626:2e07] Unexpected error in -[UIAXElement_0xad343c initialize], /SourceCache/UIAutomation_Sim/UIAutomation-271/Framework/UIAXElement.m line 165, kAXErrorServerNotFound
>
> 2013-02-22 13:12:17.828 ScriptAgent[16626:2e07]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'kUIAExeceptionAccessibilityError', reason: 'Unexpected error in -[UIAXElement_0xad343c initialize], /SourceCache/UIAutomation_Sim/UIAutomation-271/Framework/UIAXElement.m line 165, kAXErrorServerNotFound'
>
> First throw call stack:
>   (0x491012 0x1b78e7e 0x490deb 0xa8a55b 0x1b797cf 0x1b80a0d 0x1b77aeb 0x1b77e22 0x1b8a0e1 0xaa2605 0xa847 0x5d8d 0x866d 0x2925)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>
> 2013-02-22 13:12:18.264 instruments[16585:2227] Automation Instrument ran into an exception while trying to run the script.  UIAScriptAgentSignaledException
>
> 2013-02-22 19:12:18 +0000 Fail: An error occurred while trying to run the script.
>   Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 41.326542s; Output : /Users/newmanp/Work/iOS/CMAiPad/CMA.Mobile/UIScripts/instrumentscli3.trace)

I search on kAXAccessibilityLoaded or kAXErrorServerNotFound and get no hits at all. Here's what my command line call looks like:

> instruments -t ~/Work/iOS/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform//Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Users/newmanp/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.0/Applications/B60B9BD7-357D-49AA-9E6F-986929C5D151/CMA.app -e UIASCRIPT ./cmaAutomationTests.js -e UIARESULTSPATH "."

Any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong in the way you're running it. Those errors are quite strange. I've never seen those before and I run UI Automation against several apps daily. I'm wondering if something is wrong with your Xcode install. To try to isolate the problem, download my sample project at https://github.com/jonathanpenn/AutomationExample and run the `./runautomation.sh` script to see if you get the same results. If you do, then that means your install is borked. If not, then it must be something special about your project.

Comment: Yep, basically the same thing with your project - +[UIAXElement initialize]: UIAutomation never received kAXAccessibilityLoaded.  Waited 20.02 seconds. Unexpected error in -[UIAXElement_0xad343c initialize], /SourceCache/UIAutomation_Sim/UIAutomation-271/Framework/UIAXElement.m line 165, kAXErrorServerNotFound

Comment: So how do I re-install Instruments?

Comment: This started happening to me after installing xcode 4.6. My automation was working in 4.5.2.

Comment: After I deleted 4.6 and got back 4.5.2 though I am seeing this message -+[UIAXElement initialize]: UIAutomation never received kAXAccessibilityLoaded. Waited 20.02 seconds. Now I am able to run the automation.

Answer (score 10):

We saw this error when "Enable UI Automation" wasn't turned on in the "Developer" section of the "Settings" app.  Turning on the setting resolved the error.

Comment: I have to launch Xcode and run a dummy App on the iOS device. This seems to initialize something on the phone but I am not sure what it is. After doing this the command line works. Any idea if this can be done with the command line?

Comment: This was exactly the problem that I was experiencing

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, try

```
sudo rm /tmp/instruments_sock
```

You can see it here https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/172

Comment: Be sure not to use sudo appium when you re-run it always just appium.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but /tmp/instruments_sock could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

My UIAScriptAgentSignaledException is resolved by enabling the 'Enable UI Automation' option in iPhone/Settings/Developer/UI Automation section.